# How can I find users that didn't set a password?

Tags: user-registration, password, users

Is it possible to find (and bulk delete) users that registered on my WordPress site but never set a password over their confirmation email?

Comment: Just to make it clear. You want to delete users who 1. Never changed their password after registration? 2. Never logged in? 3. Something else?

Comment: By default, a user can set his password only after he clicked a link in the verification email, is that correct? I want to delete users that never clicked that link if that's possible.

Comment: are you using multisite or single WP?

Comment: I have a single site